# Equation of the plane tangent to the given surface

Tags: linear-algebra, analysis, vector-spaces, transformation

Find the equation of a plane tangent to the surface given by $$xyz+x^2-3y^2+z^3=14$$ at $$P=\left( 5,-2,3 \right)$$
In my opinion answer is: $$4x+27y+25z-41=0$$ If not please tell me what am i doing wrong.

Comment: you need to check the z component of the gradient

Comment: You mean i need to plug the value of the point into the equation of the plane and if everything is correct then the equation will give a proper result i.e. 0?

Comment: check the differentiation

Comment: precisely what do you mean by that because i do not understand

Comment: You should obtain $4x+27y+17z=\dots$.

Comment: Did I mess up in my answer? I got 21 not 27

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In order to make the function a surface, take $ x(y, z) $ to be $ x $ as a function of $y, z $. Then your equation becomes,

$$
x(y, z)yz + x(y, z)^2 - 3y^3 + z^3 = 14
$$

Without solving for $ x $, we find the slope of $ x(y, z) $ in the y and z directions,

$$
\partial_y x(y,z) y z + xz + 2 x \partial_y x - 9y^2 = 0 \\
\partial_z x(y,z) y z + xy + 2 x \partial_z x + 3z^2 = 0
$$

Solving for the derivatives at the given point, $ P=(5, -2, 3) $

$$
\partial_y x(y, z) = \frac{21}{4} \\
\partial_z x(y, z) = \frac{17}{4}
$$

We can then construct a tangent plane at
$$
4(x - 5) = 21(y + 2) + 17(z - 3)
$$
by the standard formula. Notice that the derivatives match and the tangent touches at the given point.